# Xcode/Cocoa: "object.property = value" sporadically failing? Can anyone explain this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variable-assignment

I'm writing a project where a very straightforward assignment is sporadically failing. Fascinated with this result and curious to see what y'all make of it.

I've got a project with a large data set, and I'm creating and display a modal window to present some details about a new class instance. So I've got a window with a custom window controller class, with the following code:

```
MyWindowController.h:

#import <DataModel.h>

@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController
@property (nonatomic, weak) FooClass *fooInstance;
@end

MyWindowController.m:

@implementation MyWindowController

@synthesize fooInstance = _fooInstance;

-(void) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       self.fooInstance = [FooClass new];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Totally cookie-cutter, right? But when I first added the form and ran it a bunch of times, the assignment failed over and over again. self.fooInstance kept coming back as nil. I even confirmed that the FooClass initializer was running (stepped right through it) and returning a non-null pointer to a valid FooClass instance. And yet, after the assignment line, self.fooInstance remained null.

I ran it a bunch of times, watching this same result over and over again. Then, I replaced *just* the assignment statement with this:

```
FooClass *foo = [FooClass new];
self.fooInstance = foo;
```

...and the assignment suddenly started working, and it's run consistently ever since. Even when I reverted the code back to self.fooInstance = [FooClass new], it's worked perfectly.

I couldn't believe it... until I saw it happen AGAIN, in the same project, while banging out the same type of window for a different class.

I don't understand what's happening. The self.fooInstance accessors are totally @synthesized; there is no code running in the background that might be futzing with the class (it's a single-threaded modal window); and there's nothing bound to the class. It just... doesn't work. It's like the code for the window classes doesn't run right until it's run a few times to break it in.

What in the world is happening? Does anyone even hazard a guess that might explain this behavior?

Comment: Any reason why you're using a `weak` reference to `fooInstance`? Seems like you'd want a `strong` reference... It's probably getting released out from under you while you're showing the modal view.

Comment: @MarkAdams: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I think @CodaFi has it pretty well covered now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend taking a read through [Mike Ash's explanation of weak pointers](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html).  This section is the relevant bit:

> **Weak References**
>
> First, what is a weak reference? Simply put, a weak
>   reference is a reference (pointer, in Objective-C land) to an object
>   which does not participate in keeping that object alive. For example,
>   using memory management, this setter creates a weak reference to the
>   new object:
>
> ```
> - (void)setFoo: (id)newFoo
> {
>     _foo = newFoo;
> }
> ```
>
> Because the setter does not use retain, the reference does not keep the new object alive. It will stay alive as long as it's retained
>   by other references, of course. But once those go away, the object
>   will be deallocated even if _foo still points to it.

OK, that explains the first part, but why does the second part work?

Well, when you write an instance variable like:

```
FooClass *foo = //assignment
```

The compiler says to itself "it's a really good idea to keep this thing around, (at least til the function goes out of scope under ARC), and it turns it into this:

```
__strong FooClass *foo = //assignment
```

That means whatever I assigned is retained, and therefore, because at least one object owns it, I can assign it to my weak instance variable.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Thank you! I keep confusing bits of ARC with garbage collection - momentarily thought that "strong" = "only let me throw this away," and that "weak" = "don't discard this while I hold this pointer, but if anyone else deletes it, just set me to null." I remember now that you're correct, and will fix my code posthaste.
Thank you for such a clear, direct, and non-patronizing reply - truly a great example of Stack Overflow working well.